Does Query Store track extended stored procedures?
My experiments suggest that Query Store does not track extended stored procedures. However, they each have their own individual behaviour, I am not even a beginner on the topic of extended stored procedures, and I have only tried a couple. I seek a definitive way of knowing if Query Store can track any extended stored procedure.
Do any of the following exist?

An architectural reason why Query Store cannot track any extended stored procedure at all (e.g. I find that the ones that I've tried don't have query plans, but I don't know if that's true of all extended stored procedures).
Documentation that clearly states that Query Store does not track any extended stored procedure. I couldn't find any.
Code proving that Query Store can track at least one extended stored procedure.


In a word, no.
An extended stored procedure is a very different animal than a stored procedure. (The similarity in names is unfortunate.)
A stored procedure is typically T-SQL code and typically performs actions on the various objects in a SQL database. Those actions are the kind of things that Query Store can track.
On the other hand, an extended stored procedure is typically written in an external programming language such as C or C++. Such code typically does non-SQL activities, often in the form of a function implemented in a DLL. As such, those activities are not the kind of things that Query Store can track.
If the code of the extended stored procedure ends up looping back into the SQL database to do something, Query Store could end up having visibility into that something. Even so, that's just Query Store tracking the SQL actions -- it's not tracking the extended stored procedure.
Deprecation note:
User-created extended stored procedures are on the deprecation path. See Deprecated Database Engine features in SQL Server 2016 (13.x). And from Querying Extended Stored Procedures Installed in SQL Server:

This feature will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use CLR integration instead.

